# Bounce mail error Read Java

Tags: java, email, email-bounces

I am building a java application for a company to send mass mail. Please help me hoe I could red the Bounce mail error code. Actually I want to define Hard bounce and Soft Bounce. Below is Bounce Code, Bounce Type and Bounce Description.

```
code    Type    Description

5.0.0   Hard    Address does not exist
5.1.0   Hard    Other address status
5.1.1   Hard    Bad destination mailbox address
5.1.2   Hard    Bad destination system address
5.1.3   Hard    Bad destination mailbox address syntax
5.1.4   Hard    Destination mailbox address ambiguous
5.1.5   Hard    Destination mailbox address valid
5.1.6   Hard    Mailbox has moved
5.1.7   Hard    Bad sender\’s mailbox address syntax
5.1.8   Hard    Bad sender’s system address
5.2.0   Soft    Other or undefined mailbox status
5.2.1   Soft    Mailbox disabled, not accepting messages
5.2.2   Soft    Mailbox full
5.2.3   Hard    Message length exceeds administrative limit.
5.2.4   Hard    Mailing list expansion problem
5.3.0   Hard    Other or undefined mail system status
5.3.1   Soft    Mail system full
5.3.2   Hard    System not accepting network messages
5.3.3   Hard    System not capable of selected features
5.3.4   Hard    Message too big for system
5.4.0   Hard    Other or undefined network or routing status
5.4.1   Hard    No answer from host
5.4.2   Hard    Bad connection
5.4.3   Hard    Routing server failure
5.4.4   Hard    Unable to route
5.4.5   Soft    Network congestion
5.4.6   Hard    Routing loop detected
5.4.7   Hard    Delivery time expired
5.5.0   Hard    Other or undefined protocol status
5.5.1   Hard    Invalid command
5.5.2   Hard    Syntax error
5.5.3   Soft    Too many recipients
5.5.4   Hard    Invalid command arguments
5.5.5   Hard    Wrong protocol version
5.6.0   Hard    Other or undefined media error
5.6.1   Hard    Media not supported
5.6.2   Hard    Conversion required and prohibited
5.6.3   Hard    Conversion required but not supported
5.6.4   Hard    Conversion with loss performed
5.6.5   Hard    Conversion failed
5.7.0   Hard    Other or undefined security status
5.7.1   Hard    Delivery not authorized, message refused
5.7.2   Hard    Mailing list expansion prohibited
5.7.3   Hard    Security conversion required but not possible
5.7.4   Hard    Security features not supported
5.7.5   Hard    Cryptographic failure
5.7.6   Hard    Cryptographic algorithm not supported
5.7.7   Hard    Message integrity failure
9.1.1   Hard    Hard bounce with no bounce code found. It could be an invalid email or rejected email from your mail server (such as from a sending limit).
```

Please share me your approaches.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What library are you using to send said mail?

Comment: I use mail.jar and activation.jar to send mail.

Comment: 5xx codes are hard bounces, 4xx are soft failures, as per https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3463#section-2

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the sort of thing you're after:
[Jack's Java Code Depot - detect bounced emails part 2](http://javaclue.blogspot.com.au/2009/09/detect-bounced-emails-part-2.html)

I haven't tried it myself but I found it while looking for something along the same lines as what you're trying to do.